# ASP .Net Core edit record inline without using javascript

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to send edited value in URL Action? Below a sample of my code:

`@result.Name` -> it is a value from viewbaglist (and it is what i want to override and pass in Name=...)

```
<div contenteditable="true" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { event.preventDefault(); location.href='@Url.Action("UpdateInline", "Home", new { Name = })'}">
@result.Name
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are two ways to send the edited value to a controller action method. One is to submit the Edit Form, the other is using JavaScript or JQuery Ajax method.

Without using JavaScript or JQuery, we could only using the Submit Form method to submit the form (with the edited value) to to action method. Like this (click the submit button to post the model to Edit action):

```
@model MVCSample.Models.MyEntity
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div>
                 the edit field content...
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides, It seems that you are using JavaScript in your code right now, when a user is pressing a key (using the onkeydown event), it will execute the JavaScript script. So, if you want to get the edited value and add it to the url, try to modify your code as below:

```
   <div contenteditable="true" id="nameinput" 
        onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { event.preventDefault(); location.href = ('@Url.Action("UpdateInline", "Home")?name=' + document.getElementById('nameinput').innerHTML.trim()) }">
        @result.Name
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" asp-action="UpdateInline" id="myForm">          
      <input name="NewName" value="@result.Name" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" style="background-color:transparent; border:none" />
</form>
```